# Make a where or any clause in a IRepository pattern with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inversion-of-control, repository-pattern

I have taken over a project from a collegue, who uses the IRepository pattern. I have never used it before, so I have some problems understanding how to make a `WHERE` clause or an `ANY` clause.

Previously I had the following code, which uses the DataContext repository (the actual implementation, where I can use where clauses:

```
        IQueryable<Office> officeList = repository.Offices;

        if (specification.CountryId > 0)
        {
            officeList = repository.Offices.Where(c => c.CountryId == specification.CountryId);
        }
        if (specification.LetterSize != null)
        {
            officeList =
                officeList.Where(
                    c => c.OfficeProducts.Any(d => d.OfficeProductDetail.Size == (int)specification.LetterSize));
        }

        return officeList.ToList();
```

I would like to understand how to get a code snippet like the one above to work using the IRepository pattern. I have tried to make an implementation of a WHERE/QUERY, but could not get it to work.

My question:

- How do you implement a WHERE/ANY statement in practice, so I can do something like the code snippet above?

**My IRepository**:

```
public interface IRepository
    {
        T GetById<T>(long id) where T : class;
        void Create<T>(T entity) where T : class;
        void Update<T>(T entity) where T : class;
        void SaveOrUpdate<T>(T entity) where T : class;
        void Delete<T>(T entity) where T : class;

        IList<T> FindAll<T>(params OrderBy[] orders) where T : class;
        int Count<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression) where T : class;
        bool Exists<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression) where T : class;

        T FindFirst<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression, params OrderBy[] orders) where T : class;
        PaginatedResult<T> Find<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression, int pageIndex, int pageSize, params OrderBy[] orders) where T : class;

        void ExecuteNativeSQL(string sql);
    }
```

**The implementation:**

```
public class EFRepository : IRepository
    {
        private IDBFactory databaseFactory;
        private LetterAmazerContext dataContext;

        public EFRepository(IDBFactory databaseFactory)
        {
            this.databaseFactory = databaseFactory;
        }

        protected LetterAmazerContext DataContext
        {
            get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = databaseFactory.Get()); }
        }

        public T GetById<T>(long id) where T : class
        {
            IDbSet<T> dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
            return dbset.Find(id);
        }

        public void Create<T>(T entity) where T : class
        {
            IDbSet<T> dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
            dbset.Add(entity);
        }

        public void Update<T>(T entity) where T : class
        {
            dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public void SaveOrUpdate<T>(T entity) where T : class
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Delete<T>(T entity) where T : class
        {
            IDbSet<T> dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
            dbset.Remove(entity);
        }

        public IList<T> FindAll<T>(params OrderBy[] orders) where T : class
        {
            IDbSet<T> dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
            var query = dbset.Where(t => true);
            query = ApplyOrders<T>(query, orders);
            return query.ToList<T>();
        }

        public int Count<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression) where T : class
        {
            IDbSet<T> dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
            return dbset.Count<T>(whereExpression);
        }

        public bool Exists<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression) where T : class
        {
            IDbSet<T> dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
            return dbset.Count<T>(whereExpression) != 0;
        }

        public T FindFirst<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression, params OrderBy[] orders) where T : class
        {
            IDbSet<T> dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
            var query = dbset.Where(whereExpression);
            query = ApplyOrders<T>(query, orders);
            return query.SingleOrDefault<T>();
        }

        public PaginatedResult<T> Find<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression, int pageIndex, int pageSize, params OrderBy[] orders) where T : class
        {
            IDbSet<T> dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
            PaginatedResult<T> results = new PaginatedResult<T>();
            var query = dbset.AsExpandable().Where(whereExpression);
            query = ApplyOrders<T>(query, orders);
            results.Results = query.Skip<T>(pageIndex * pageSize).Take<T>(pageSize).ToList<T>();
            results.TotalItems = dbset.AsExpandable().LongCount(whereExpression);
            return results;
        }

        public void ExecuteNativeSQL(string sql)
        {
            DataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
        }

        private IQueryable<T> ApplyOrders<T>(IQueryable<T> query, params OrderBy[] orders)
        {
            if (orders == null || orders.Length == 0) return query;
            foreach (var order in orders)
            {
                query = query.OrderBy(order.ToString());
            }
            return query;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26667/Implementing-the-Repository-Pattern-with-LINQ-to-S

Comment: This is a bad implementation of the Repository pattern i.e is not the Repo pattern. At this point, skip it alltogether and use directly EF. If you really want to use the Repository , do it properly and don't expose ANYTHING related to EF (entities, linq). But in that case you can't use expression directly and you'd have to either have multiple dedicated method for fetching or to define Criteria objects that will be then use by the repo to create EF queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your repository is at the moment open for arbitrary expressions, including potentially expressions that cannot be evaluated by the implementation.

On one hand this is a potential risk of not being able to deliver an implementation that matches so open contract.

On the other hand, why don't you just then expose it a bit more:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    ...
    IQueryable<T> Query<T>();
}
```

and

```
public class EFRepository : IRepository
{
   ...
   public IQueryable<T> Query<T>()
   {
       return DataContrxt.Set<T>();
   }
}
```

Note that if you decide to go that way, most of your specific query methods doesn't make sense anymore as such open generic queryable interface satisfies most needs.

Note also that the same concern applies there, if you have multiple implementations you can't possibly guarantee that the contract is satisfied in the same way. Also, your potential client can easily create a query the provider will reject. If you accept these issues, the proposed solution solves your issue as you can now query the repository for almost anything.

And the last note, if you don't plan to have multiple implementations, remove the repository layer completely. The EF context **is** a unit of work with repositories inside. Starting from version 6, the context can be mocked so unit testing is possible.

Comment: Thanks very thorough answer!